# strcpy() function giving unexpected behaviour in output

Tags: c

I was learning to swap arrays in C but then I arrived at these problems where I'm not getting the desired output.
**Question 1:** Please explain me how strcpy() works and what is the cause of this output as I have shown below. Why nothing gets copied to 'x'?

**Question 2:** Also a youtuber said we can fix this by assigning max length to character arrays inside the square brackets of each variables like this:

```
char x[15] = "water";
char y[15] = "soda";
char temp[15];
```

And it works, but what is the reason here? Please explain these 2 questions.

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char x[] = "water";
    char y[] = "soda";
    char temp[15];

    strcpy(temp, x); 
    strcpy(x, y); 
    strcpy(y, temp);

    printf("x = %s\n", x);
    printf("y = %s", y);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output: (Both VS Code and Code Blocks are giving this same output)**

```
x =
y = water
```

Comment: One reason for UB is that the compiler dimensions `x[]` to be 5+1 and `y[]` to be 4+1. When the last statement copies "water" into `y[]`, it overflows the buffer clobbering the first character of `x[]` with the `'\0'` spilling out of `y[]`... If you want to put 5+1 characters into both buffers, then **both** must have enough room to store the longest string (and its nul terminator)... PS: You may not have seen this symptom/problem had the compiler arranged things differently. The compiler is allowed to do that.

Comment: @Fe2O3 That very neatly explains the observed behaviour, in fact. Even without supposing any weird tricks and that the compiler approaches the UB in a very naive way... one possibility is that the allocation for `x` immediately follows the allocation for `y` in memory, and the `strcpy` into `y` is thus dropping a null byte into `x[0]`.

Comment: "And it works, but what is the reason here?" - well, **what did the youtuber say** is the reason?

Comment: With `char y[] = "soda";` you create an array of exactly five elements (including the null-terminator). With `char x[] = "water";` you have an array of *six* elements. Six elements can't fit in an array of only five elements.

Answer (score 1):

The C library function `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)` copies the string pointed to by `src` to `dest`.

Note that if the destination array `dest` is not large enough and the length of the source string is too long, a buffer overflow may result.

This is just an example. You may try doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char x[] = "water";
    char y[] = "soda";
    char temp[15];

    strcpy(temp, x); 
    strcpy(x, y); 
    strcpy(y, temp);
    printf("location of x in RAM %p - %p\n", (void*)&x[0], (void*)&x[5]);
    printf("location of y in RAM %p - %p\n", (void*)&y[0], (void*)&y[5]);
    printf("location of temp in RAM %p - %p\n", (void*)&temp[0], (void*)&temp[15]);
    printf("x = %s\n", x);
    printf("y = %s", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Seeing the location of the variables, and if you use a debugger in the program to see in the addresses of the variables, you will find that, when you `strcpy(x,y)`, the `'\0'` at the end of `x`, is put where it should be `&y[5]` but it is, at the same time, `&x[0]`.

Thus x begins with an `'\0'`, nothing will be printed.

You should make sure that the length of char arrays are enough to use `strcpy` function.

Comment: Oops, as a new user of StackOverflow, I even do not have enough `reputation` to directly comment. If you have difficulties understanding what I am doing, for example you cannot understand what a pointer is, feel free to comment below.

Comment: You might want to add that the behavior is not guaranteed as the compiler may allocate the `x`, `y` and `temp` arrays differently in the stack frame...

Comment: `strcpy(y, temp);` still has undefined behavior in your example program so it could crash instead of showing the locations in memory.

Comment: Well, I checked it using MinGW-w64(gcc.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0), using `gcc main.c -o main.exe` and it worked. I didn't check other compilers. But I suppose that using address in RAM will be the best method to explain what was happening. I checked some docs and found that some compilers like clang may not allow such code to run as I wish... Thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: @szw0407 _"and it worked"_ - That's one possible outcome when a program has undefined behavior. It may seem to work but could at the same time cause problems that are hard to discover. Enable the AddressSanitizer in gcc and you'll see: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/s98qT5ohW)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare and initialize a C char array like so:

```
char x[] = "water";
```

The compiler helps you out and determines that `x` needs to be able to store exactly 6 `char` values. The extra is for the null terminator.

If you do the work of specifying the length:

```
char x[15] = "water";
```

Then you have an array that can store *15* `char` values. It's initialized with the string literal provided, but the other 9 are available, initialized to `'\0'` and can be safely accessed.

In your code, `x` can contain 6 characters, but `y` can only contain *5*, so trying to copy `"water"` into `y` causes the null terminator to be written out of bounds. This is where your undefined behavior comes from.

Depending on how the memory in your program is laid out, the result may be the program apparently "working."

This is one of the most dangerous outcomes of undefined behavior as it hides problems.

Allocating more memory is one way of avoiding this issue, but you can also use functions like [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) which allow you to specify the size of the destination buffer to prevent out of bounds writes. If you use this, be careful to ensure that you have null-terminated your string.

Comment: [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) may be able to prevent out-of-bounds writes, but it also creates opportunities for out-of-bounds *reads* down the road, when it fails to null-terminate the buffer in specific scenarios. The user is advised to read the documentation very carefully.

Comment: I'm afraid advocating the use of `strncpy` is not helping C beginners, even with the extra caveat about null termination. The `n` argument in `strncpy` is not a number of characters to copy, it is the size of the destination array for null padding and truncation.  If all 3 arrays are defined with the same size, `memcpy` could be used safely even if the strings are not null terminated.

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof x == sizeof y, "unsafe swap");` could also help to get a compile-time error if only swapping of equal sized `char` arrays are to be supported.